# How to hide certain elements and lift other elements up in Kivy

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

I created the following GUI with Kivy.

[image]

When I click the button, I want to design so that testTextInput2 disappears and testTextInput3 rises.

I was able to design testTextInput2 to disappear, but I don't know how to make testTextInput3 lift up.

When testTextInput3 is lifted up, I want to make the area where testTextInput3 originally resided in a black area.

[image]

I wrote the following code

**main.py**

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

from kivy.properties import NumericProperty 

class TestWidget(Widget):
    testTextInput2_Opacity = NumericProperty()
    testTextInput2_size_hint_y = NumericProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TestWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.testTextInput2_Opacity = 1
        self.testTextInput2_size_hint_y = 0.2

    def buttonClicked(self):
        self.testTextInput2_Opacity = 0
        self.testTextInput2_size_hint_y = 0.0


class TestApp(App):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TestApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self):
        return TestWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

**test.kv**

```
TestWidget: # ルートに追加

<TestWidget>:
    BoxLayout:
        size: root.size
        orientation: 'vertical'

        Button:
            size_hint_y: 0.4
            on_press: root.buttonClicked()
            text: 'layoutChangeButton'

        BoxLayout:
            id:testTextInput1
            size_hint_y: 0.2
            opacity: 1.0
            Label:
                text: 'testTextInput1'

            TextInput:
                text: ''

        BoxLayout:
            id:testTextInput2
            size_hint_y: 0.2
            opacity: root.testTextInput2_Opacity
            Label:
                text: 'testTextInput2'

            TextInput:
                text: ''

        BoxLayout:
            id:testTextInput3
            size_hint_y: 0.2
            opacity: 1.0
            Label:
                text: 'testTextInput3'

            TextInput:
                text: ''
```

Finally, I want to make the GUI after clicking the button look like the image below.

How can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do that is to

- make the `testTextInput2` transparent (as you already do)
- remove it from the parent `Boxlayout`
- re-add it to the parent layout as the last widget

So, first you have to set an `id` for the parent `BoxLayout`

```py
<TestWidget>:
    BoxLayout:
        id: box  # <--- add an id here
        size: root.size
        orientation: 'vertical'
```

and then change a little your `buttonClicked` method (remember indexes are reversed in kivy, so to add something to the bottom/last we need to put it at the 0 index...)

```py
    def buttonClicked(self):
        self.ids.box.remove_widget(self.ids.testTextInput2)
        self.ids.box.add_widget(self.ids.testTextInput2, 0)
        self.testTextInput2_Opacity = 0
        self.testTextInput2_size_hint_y = 0.0
```

[image]